# How to disable syntax coloring in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to disable syntax coloring altogether.

I have tried to disable parameter hints but that didn't have any effect.

Is it possible to have the editor with just a foreground/background color and nothing else?

Comment: Also if anyone needs disabling it temporarily, I've opened an issue for it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132796

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Search the extensions marketplace for "plain theme".  There are a couple which might to the trick for you: Plain Theme, Plain Light Theme and Nando Theme.

Comment: do you know how to disable syntax highlighting for php or any docblock?

Answer (score 15):

You can add

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.*": "plaintext",
},
```

to `settings.json`

Answer (score 6):

I use the [Gray Matter Light](https://vscodethemes.com/e/philipbe.theme-gray-matter) theme for everything at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the text language to plain text. You'll have to reset the language to plain text for each document you open but it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer.

You can write code to mess with VSCode user settings JSON (it is just a JSON), so you can customize the syntax color as you wish.

The following gist loads scopes from Python magic repo, then modifies `user_settings.json` in place, assigning a light gray color for Python elements:

https://gist.github.com/shuoli84/93fead0a634d711dc25494acd127c180